# Is since_id a supported parameter for Order count?

Tags: shopify

To receive a list of Orders one of the many parameters you can pass to restrict results is `since_id`.

I've noticed that [the Order API documentation](http://api.shopify.com/order.html) for receiving a count of Orders lists many of those same filter parameters, like `created_at_min` and co.

`since_id` is not listed as one of the available URL parameters. However, at least using the `shopify_api` gem, passing `since_id` works as expected:

```
ShopifyAPI::Order.count(since_id: 1234)
```

Is this an omission in the documentation, or is it an unsupported feature?

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: As a minor note that should be: `ShopifyAPI::Order.count(:since_id => 1234)`

Comment: The old was valid, however I've updated it for clarity. Note this is ruby 1.9 syntax :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, wasn't familiar with the newer 1.9 syntax for such.  (And tried with 1.8 before opening my mouth ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

It **is** listed as an available parameter :)

Update: Here’s a screenshot: [image]

Comment: Nick: ah, it looks like it’s missing from the Orders/count API documentation. I’ll add it there as well.

Comment: (Note that the docs have since been updated and reflect the since_id docs.)